# Why is asterisk not highlighting repeated occurences of a character?

Tags: regular-expression, search

I am using the latest version of Gvim on Windows 10.

When I type `/` and some expression, for example `/a`, I see all matches in the document highlighted.

The documentation says that the asterisk symbol `*` will match repeated occurrences of the same character, for example, `*n` will match `nnnn`.

However, when I type `/*n` or `/\*n`, nothing is highlighted, and when I press enter, I receive the message "Pattern not found", even though the word "Connect" is in the document.

When I enter `/n*`, the entire document is highlighted.

Does this indicate the asterisk has had its meaning remapped due to some Windows configuration or is there some other reason I am not able to match repeated instances of characters? What can I do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The question is basically about (standard) regex, not Vim.
2. Quantifier, such as an asterisk, applies to what it follows, not what it precedes, i.e. `n*`, not `*n`.
3. The asterisk means "zero or more". Hence `n*` matches just anything. It should probably be `nn*` or `n\+` instead.

Comment: Aha. Thank you very much.